# How to decode XHTML and/or HTML5 entities in Java?

Tags: java, xhtml, html-entities, xml-entities

I have some strings that contain **XHTML** character entities:

```
"They&apos;re quite varied"
"Sometimes the string &isin; XML standard, sometimes &isin; HTML4 standard"
"Therefore -&gt; I need an XHTML entity decoder."
"Sadly, some strings are not valid XML & are not-quite-so-valid HTML <- but I want them to work, too."
```

Is there any easy way to decode the entities? (I'm using Java)

I'm currently using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(myString.replace("&apos;", "\'"))` as a temporary hack. Sadly, `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` has `unescapeHtml4` and `unescapeXML`, but no `unescapeXhtml`.

EDIT: I do want to handle invalid XML, for example I want "&&xyzzy;" to decode to "&&xyzzy;"

EDIT: I think HTML5 has almost the same character entities as XHTML, so I think HTML **5** decoder would be fine too.

Comment: Aren't XHTML and HTML entities equivalent?

Comment: hint: XHTML is valid XML

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No. That's the problem.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If the input was guaranteed to be **valid** XHTML, then I'd be happy. Furthermore, XML by itself doesn't have all the HTML references.

Comment: Wikipedia says [otherwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: `&apos;` is not a character entity reference in HTML4.

Comment: @KarolS XHTML only has the additional `apos` over HTML4, so it looks like your "temporary hack" should work. Unless it doesn't handle the errors you mention?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis XML documents by themselves only know about the five XML entity names. XHTML documents need extra input (in the form of an XHTML doctype) to be able to handle all the HTML ones. And the HTML5 doctype in an XHTML file (so-called XHTML5) doesn't work; such documents can't handle entity names beyond the XML ones.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be directly relevant but you may wish to adopt [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) which handles things like that albeit from a higher level. Includes web page cleaning routines.

Comment: Thanks, looks great, but in my use case it would be an overkill.

Comment: There is no such thing as overkill - only problems and solutions. JSoup is a solution and a far better one than doing manual search & replaces.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to implement a XHTMLStringEscapeUtils based on the facilities provide by [org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)?

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.*;

public class XHTMLStringEscapeUtils {
    public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_XHTML =
            new AggregateTranslator(
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_ESCAPE),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_ESCAPE),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE)
            ).with(StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML11);

    public static final CharSequenceTranslator UNESCAPE_XHTML =
            new AggregateTranslator(
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_UNESCAPE),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_UNESCAPE),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_UNESCAPE),
                    new NumericEntityUnescaper(),
                    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.APOS_UNESCAPE)
            );

    public static final String escape(final String input) {
        return ESCAPE_XHTML.translate(input);
    }

    public static final String unescape(final String input) {
        return UNESCAPE_XHTML.translate(input);
    }
}
```

Thanks to the modular design of Apache commons-text lib, it's easy to create custom escape utils.

You can find a full project with tests here [xhtml-string-escape-utils](https://github.com/eric-leihe/xhtml-string-escape-utils)